# How can I get a better result making math videos with a tablet?

Tags: secondary-education, technology-in-education, teaching

First question in this stack. Here it goes:

So, I had this 2 or 3 year old intuos tablet and I said why not? And started doing my own videos. I've been making my own videos for my students last couple weeks and I notice that are way more powerful than when I just assign one to them from a random channel in YouTube. In their own words the way I talk and the words that I use are more approachable to them.  However my hand writing using the tablet its awful.

So my question is: What kind of software can I used to make my digital writing as sharp as this one?
[image]

Because this is my best result:

[image]

And even tho my hand writing is not made in heaven is not as awful as that second picture.

Any ideas? My table is a Wacon Intuos Creative pen & touch tablet. If some of you have this same model it would be awesome if you can share any ideas or software to use it at full potential.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have tried a professional tablet like the Wacom and still the quality is poor, I only have two words to say: document camera.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have the old model of this one: goo.gl/8N4bBX. I don't see it as the pro version since I can find one around the 300 USD mark. 

My whole idea is to squeeze the best out of the one I got before commiting to keep making more videos more frecuently. That's why I wonder if I can find better software than the ones Im using right now (Power point, OneNote) to get better results.

Comment: Why don't you buy a Samsung tablet with S-pen or an ipad with ipencil?

Comment: Well I already have an ipad (Air 1 I think), but it doesn't support the last pencils for example. I don't know how to screencast the ipad but I guess I could look into it. I don't see buying another ipad as an option since I have the tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. So, I've been looking around all day and yesterday and I found this great option: smoothdraw 4 beta. It really let me customize the pen and the flow of it improving my digital hand writing so is kinda what I was looking for. Someone told me that I should try photoshop and that the results are insanely better than anything else and I would try it in the near future.  So if anyone had this same question this could be your answer ;).

Comment: I've used Inkscape with the calligraphy mode (maybe the name of the setting is something else, it was a couple of years ago) and got very nice results. The only annoying disadvantage was, that you cannot draw a dot by simply tipping the pen on the tablet once.

Answer (score 1):

I use the app Xournal (with a Thinkpad X200 Tablet as hardware, currently available at about 200€ in very good used state) and get output like this: [image]

My handwriting could be better, but I think, it is quite smooth in terms of software. Xournal is free software, available at: http://xournal.sourceforge.net/